# ValueError: could not convert string to float, after removing unwanted characters in column (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The column which I wanted to convert had the data in this format:

```
0           74 bhp
1       103.52 bhp
2           78 bhp
3           90 bhp
4         88.2 bhp
           ...    
8123     82.85 bhp
8124       110 bhp
8125      73.9 bhp
8126        70 bhp
8127        70 bhp
Name: max_power, Length: 8128, dtype: object
```

I removed the bhp using this code `copy_car_details['max_power'] = copy_car_details['max_power'].replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)`

But when I add `astype(float)` in the end it throws the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

Can someone suggest a solution for this.

Comment: You don't include all of your code, but I would recommend a try/except at the point where you do the type casting, so you can throw an exception for the value that fails: `except ValueError,e:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) - in your solution if need also remove `.`:

```
copy_car_details['max_power'] = pd.to_numeric(copy_car_details['max_power'].replace(r'\D', '', regex=True))
```

Or if need remove only  `bhp` and not `.`:

```
copy_car_details['max_power'] = pd.to_numeric(copy_car_details['max_power'].str.strip('bhp '))
```

Another idea if need extract values with `.`:

```
copy_car_details['max_power'] = pd.to_numeric(copy_car_details['max_power'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False))
```